# "initMap is not a function" with EXIF.js is NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked many times before , but i can not seem to find the answer for my case . There is something i am not seeing and i apologies in advance . 
My task is to create a gallery of images and when i click on one of them the image to become bigger and next to it to be displayed EXIF data and location of where the picture was take .

I have extracted everything , just the location is not showing and in the console i keep getting the message "initMap is not a function" and the error is pointed to the first line of code in the HTML `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I have tried with moving the `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"" async="false"></script>` place in the HTML ....no success.
Changing `async="false"` - > async="defer". 
Removing the `callback=initMap` from the google link as suggested in one of the previously asked questions.

Tried calling the function after the code in the .js file and before . 
I am missing something very basic i am sure , just can not seem to find it.

```
<div id="imageContainer"></div>
 <div>
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">
     <img id="current" class="modal-content" >
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <pre id="exifResult"></pre>
     <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
```

```
let $modal = $('.modal')
let $img = $("#imageContainer img");

$img.click(function(){
$('.modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
$modal.css('display', 'block')
var imgCurrent = document.getElementById('current');

EXIF.getData(imgCurrent,function(){
    let result = $('#exifResult')
    let make = EXIF.getAllTags(this);

    let exifData = Object.entries(make).map(([property, value]) => {
        return `${property}: ${value}`;
    })
    result.text(exifData.join('\n'));

  let latDegree = this.exifdata.GPSLatitude[0].numerator;
  let latMinute = this.exifdata.GPSLatitude[1].numerator;
  let latSecond = this.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2].numerator;
  let latDirection = this.exifdata.GPSLatitudeRef;
  let latFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(latDegree, latMinute, latSecond, latDirection);

  let lonDegree = this.exifdata.GPSLongitude[0].numerator;
  let lonMinute = this.exifdata.GPSLongitude[1].numerator;
  let lonSecond = this.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2].numerator;
  let lonDirection = this.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef;
  let lonFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(lonDegree, lonMinute, lonSecond, lonDirection);


  function initMap() {
     var mapOptions = {
        center: {lat: latFinal, lng: lonFinal},
        zoom: 8
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         mapOptions
      });
  }
});


  function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    var dd = degrees + (minutes/60) + (seconds/3600);
    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1; 
      }
      return dd;
  }
})
```

Comment: `initMap` is declared inside the `Exif.getData` callback, which is inside the `click` handler - so, it's not *visible* anywhere else - you could call initMap inside that callback - but then every time you hit `click` it would create a new map - did you only want to show the map on that click?

Comment: I want on click on  a image the map to be related to the place where that image was taken. So on every click it would change. When i close the modal dialog , it closes and only the gallery remains . And again the same thing. Do you mean to just `initMar()`  call it before the` EXIF.getDate` function . I have placed it in the exif data function because the map take the longitute and latitutude from the exif data , which will be local data for this function only . This is why i am a little bit confused of where exactly should i call it .

Comment: call it where you CAN call it

Answer (score 0):

I did it by making the `initMap()` function global and called it with an

`If(statement){
   initMap()
 }`

in the `EXIF.getData()` function.

```
$img.click(function() {
$('.modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
$modal.css('display', 'block');;
const imgCurrent = document.getElementById('current');

EXIF.getData(imgCurrent, function() {
    const result = $('#exifResult')
    const make = EXIF.getAllTags(this);

    let exifData = Object.entries(make).map(([property, value]) => {
        return `${property}: ${value}`;
    })
    result.text(exifData.join('\n'));

    let latFinal;
    if (imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLatitude && imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLatitude.length > 0) {
        const latDegree = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLatitude[0].numerator;
        const latMinute = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLatitude[1].numerator;
        const latSecond = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2].numerator;

        const latDirection = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLatitudeRef;
        latFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(latDegree, latMinute, latSecond, latDirection);
    }

    let lonFinal;
    if (imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef && imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef.length > 0) {

        const lonDegree = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLongitude[0].numerator;
        const lonMinute = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLongitude[1].numerator;
        const lonSecond = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2].numerator;

        const lonDirection = imgCurrent.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef;
        lonFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(lonDegree, lonMinute, lonSecond, lonDirection);
    }

    if (latFinal && lonFinal) {
        initMap(latFinal, lonFinal);
    } else {
        alert('Google Location Missing');
    }

});


function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    var dd = degrees + (minutes/60) + (seconds/3600);
    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1; 
      }
      return dd;
  }
})



function initMap(lonFinal,latFinal) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: {lat: lonFinal, lng: latFinal},
       zoom: 10,
    });
}
```